# Login.aspx Looping and GetRolesForUser does not have any value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am having trouble with my Web Form app. Specifically my app keeps going back to the Login page  whenever the function GetRolesForUser return null. Here is a workflow of my app. 
An user first logs in using Login page and then redirects default.aspx if he is a ValidateUser. 
However, some Validated users (Membership.ValidateUser) when redirecting to default.aspx donot return role in GetRolesForUser( which is null). Therefore these users cannot redirect to different page( Staff/Default.aspx) even if i set role = "Officer" as a default. It still redirects them back to Login.aspx.

I dont know what is causing this problem. I check applicationName and it is correct.

Does anyone know what happens and what is causing this problem? Can you suggest a way to fix this?

web.config

```
<location path="Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Master,CanEdit"/>
            <allow roles="Admin,CanEdit"/>
            <allow roles="Staff,CanEdit"/>
            <allow roles="Officer"/>
            <allow roles="Agent"/>
            <allow roles="Front Desk"/>
            <allow roles="Manager"/>
            <deny users="?"/>
            <!--<allow users="*"/>-->
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="Login" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" path="/" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" protection="All" timeout="60"/>
</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="ApplMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="ApplMembershipProvider" 
            connectionStringName="ApplConnection" 
            applicationName="/" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true"
            requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true"
            passwordFormat="Hashed"
            minRequiredPasswordLength="3" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
            maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="30" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"/>
    </providers>
</membership>
```

Login.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox username = (TextBox)loginControl.FindControl("UserName");
    TextBox password = (TextBox)loginControl.FindControl("Password");
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(username.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(password.Text))
        {
            // set focus on the username text box when the page loads
            username.Focus();

            EmployeeSchool EmplSchool;
            string test = ApplConfiguration.DbConnectionString;
            EmplSchool = ApplSchoolUsers.GetEmployeeSchool(username.Text);
            string connection = ApplSchoolUsers.GetConnectionString(EmplSchool.School);

            ApplConfigurationSchool.ConfigureConnectionString(connection);

            string test1 = ApplConfiguration.DbConnectionString;
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(username.Text, password.Text))
            {
                string returnUrl = (string)Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
                if (returnUrl != null)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx", false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Default.aspx

```
string userName = "";
string[] UserRoles = null;
System.Web.Security.RoleProvider roleProvider = System.Web.Security.Roles.Provider;
try
{
    string test = ApplConfiguration.DbConnectionString;
    userName = Membership.GetUser().UserName.ToString();
    //it does return a valid userName
    UserRoles = roleProvider.GetRolesForUser(userName);            
    //testing
    string currUserRole = (UserRoles.Length!=0) ? UserRoles[0] : "Officer";

    switch (currUserRole)
    {
        case "Master":
            Response.Redirect("~/Adm/DefaultMaster.aspx",false);
            break;
        case "Admin":
            Response.Redirect("~/Adm/Default.aspx",false);
            break;
        case "Front Desk":
            Response.Redirect("~/Lsi/Default.aspx",false);
            break;
        case "Staff":
        case "Officer":
            Response.Redirect("~/Staff/Default.aspx",false);
            break;
        case "Manager":
            Response.Redirect("~/Manager/Default.aspx",false);
            break;
        case "Agent":
            Response.Redirect("~/Agent/Default.aspx",false);
            break;                
    }
}
```

Comment: `Debug the code` and perhaps you will find the issue / error

Comment: I did many times but could not find the bug

Comment: what do you get in this particular line when you debug
`if (Membership.ValidateUser(username.Text, password.Text))`

Comment: It always return true if i give them right username and password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing too many pieces -

1. You need `<roleManager..></roleManager>` tag in web.config if you want to use **Role Provider**.
2. **Membership.ValidateUser** is for validating user; you still need to create **FormAuthentication Cookie** by using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username , true|false);`
3. You **do not need to instantiate** `... roleProvider = System.Web.Security.Roles.Provider;` inside **Default.aspx**. You just need to call - 
   `string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name);`